How to generate rustdoc for the Rust standard library in JSON?
I'm able to generate docs in JSON for my own library.
rustdoc -Z unstable-options --output-format json --out-dir=json_docs src/lib.rs

However no luck in finding a way to do so for the the whole Rust standard library. Is it possible?

In most cases you don't need to generate the docs, the JSON rustdoc for the standard library is available with the rust-docs-json rustup component:
rustup component add --toolchain nightly rust-docs-json

If you do need to generate them, clone the repo (--depth=1 is enough) and execute
python x.py doc library -- --output-format=json


Thanks! I do appreciate the link! Also, I received a tip that you can use x.py in the rust-land repo to generate the JSON docs if need be.

@MorganWilde Indeed; if you do need to generate the docs, clone the repo --depth=1 is enough), and execute python x.py doc library.
